# How to create nested array Json using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

i have a little problem, i want to make my attribut nested, so it looks like this. can someone help me?

[image]

this is the code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once('helper_connect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$sql = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query);

if($sql){
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        array_push($result, array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'kategori' => $row['kategori'],
            'nama' => $row['nama'],
            'deskripsi' => $row['deskripsi'],
            'berat' => $row['berat'],
            'harga' => $row['harga'],
            'gambar' => $row['gambar'],
            'stock' => $row['stock'],
            'warna' => $row['warna'],
            'ukuran' => $row['ukuran'],
            'jenis_bahan' => $row['jenis_bahan'],
            'motif' => $row['motif'],
            'penutup' => $row['penutup'],
        ));
    }
    echo json_encode(array('product' => $result));
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare an array within the outer array, and then another (associative) array within that as the first index of it:

```
    array_push($result, array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'kategori' => $row['kategori'],
        'nama' => $row['nama'],
        'deskripsi' => $row['deskripsi'],
        'berat' => $row['berat'],
        'harga' => $row['harga'],
        'gambar' => $row['gambar'],
        'stock' => $row['stock'],
        'attribut' => array(
          0 => array(
            'warna' => $row['warna'],
            'ukuran' => $row['ukuran'],
            'jenis_bahan' => $row['jenis_bahan'],
            'motif' => $row['motif'],
            'penutup' => $row['penutup']
          )
        )
    ));
```